# Wicked_pdf renders PDF different when called from object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

In a controller I have a `show` method with a `respond_to` block which creates a PDF with `wicked_pdf` like this:

```
class TimesheetsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "pdf",
          template:          'timesheets/show.pdf.haml',
          print_media_type:  true,
          orientation:       'Portrait',
          page_size:         'A4',
          disposition:       'attachment'
      end
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

This works fine, but I want to use `delayed_job` to move this to a background job. I have setup `delayed_job` and it works fine. Now I want to use a `PdfJob` object to create the PDF, so it also can be done as a separate background job. So the new `respond_to` block looks like this:

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.pdf do
     PdfJob.new.create_timesheet(@timesheet)
   end
 end
```

And the `PdfJob` looks like this:

```
class PdfJob

  def initialize
  end

  def create_timesheet(timesheet)
    av = ActionView::Base.new()
    av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
    av.extend ApplicationHelper
    av.render pdf: "Timesheet #{timesheet.user.full_name} #{I18n.t("date.month_names")[timesheet.month]} #{timesheet.year}",
           template:          'timesheets/show.pdf.haml',
           print_media_type:  true,
           orientation:       'Portrait',
           page_size:         'A4',
           disposition:       'attachment'
  end

end
```

It is calling the `ActionView::Base` and `ActionController::Base` to be able to render views from an object. The actual rendering of the PDF has not changed. When I try to create a PDF however, the PDF is created inline and not as attachment, and it is completely empty. What could be the reason for this? And am I forgetting something?

Comment: You can pass the view_context: `PdfJob.new.create_timesheet(@timesheet, view_context)` and in code: `view_context.view_paths` `view_context.render :pdf` etc..

Comment: @timesheet is null check if this has values on both controllers.